# Truncated Core Data NSData objects

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, nsdata

I am saving arrays of doubles in an NSData* object that is persisted as a binary property in a Core Data (SQLite) data model. I am doing this to store sampled data for graphing in an iPhone app. Sometimes when there are more than 300 doubles in the binary object not all the doubles are getting saved to disk. When I quit and relaunch my app there may be as few as 25 data points that have persisted or as many as 300.

Using NSSQLitePragmasOption with synchronous = FULL and this may be making a difference. It is hard to tell, as bug is intermittent.

Given the warnings about performance problems as a result of using synchronous = FULL, I am seeking advice and pointers.

Thanks.

[[**Edit: here is code.**]]

The (as yet unrealized) intent of -addToCache: is to add each new datum to the cache but only flush (fault?) Data object periodically.

From Data.m

```
@dynamic dataSet; // NSData * attribute of Data entity

 - (void) addDatum:(double_t)datum
    {
    DLog(@"-[Data addDatum:%f]", datum);
    [self addToCache:datum];
    }

- (void) addToCache:(double_t)datum
    {
    if (cache == nil)
        {
        cache = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[self dataSet]];
        [cache retain];
        }
    [cache appendBytes:&datum length:sizeof(double_t)];
    DLog(@"-[Data addToCache:%f] ... [cache length] = %d; cache = %p", datum, [cache length], cache);
    [self flushCache];
    }

- (void) wrapup
    {
    DLog(@"-[Data wrapup]");
    [self flushCache];
    [cache release];
    cache = nil;
    DLog(@"[self isFault] = %@", [self isFault] ? @"YES" : @"NO"); // [self isFault] is always NO.
    }

- (void) flushCache
    {
    DLog(@"flushing cache to store");
    [self setDataSet:cache];
    DLog(@"-[Data flushCache:] [[self dataSet] length] = %d", [[self dataSet] length]);
    }

- (double*) bytes
    {
    return (double*)[[self dataSet] bytes];
    }

- (NSInteger) count
    {
    return [[self dataSet] length]/sizeof(double);
    }

- (void) dump
    {
    ALog(@"Dump Data");
    NSInteger numDataPoints = [self count];
    double *data = (double*)[self bytes];
    ALog(@"numDataPoints = %d", numDataPoints);
    for (int i = 0; i
```

Comment: Wow, if that's really a bug in the framework and not your code, I hope you file with Apple cause that's very very bad.

Comment: Have you considered creating proper entities and relationships for your data model rather than trying to store an array in a single attribute?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the data is being converted to binary properly? I would argue that the bug is most likely in the conversion code which as St3fan pointed out, we need to see.

Try, before the save, converting it back from binary into doubles and do an assertion check.  This will catch the bug if it is indeed in the conversion code.

Comment: gerry3 - not sure what you mean. I have 'Experiment' entities that have one-to-many relationships with 'Run' entities (for containment), and 'Run' entities have one-to-one relationships with 'Data' entities (though most Run attributes are stored within a Run object). A Data entity is a sample of data from a measurement, to it could hold tens of thousands of data points. If there's a better way to represent this than as a BLOB, I am all ears.

Comment: St3fan - I have added some of the code for the Data object (which is an NSManagedObject). While data is being sampled from a measurement (e.g., temperature sensor), -[Data addDatum:] is being called for each data point. When sampling is completed, -[Data wrapup] is called. The caller also calls -save on the NSManagedObjectContext.

Sometimes - for example when more than one Run is sampled during an execution of the app, or when there are already a few saved Runs - the new Run and its Data's NSData attribute are saved properly. But the first Run of an Experiment is often truncated.

Comment: Marcus - Thanks. My latest hypothesis is that the Data object is not faulted (which I take to mean differing from stored version). I tried forcing a fault (by adding a BOOL attribute which I toggled) but that didn't succeed in faulting the object.

As for conversion code, I have a method called -dump (in edited question). I think that it is doing the conversion that you suggested. It shows the full NSData after creation - even when subsequent launch of app shows truncation.

In any event, I am not sure why saving Data object's NSData would work sometimes and not others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to get behavior as if my Core Data entity could have an NSMutableData attribute. To do this my NSManagedObject (called Data) had an NSData attribute *and* an NSMutableData ivar. My app takes sample data from a sensor and appends each data point to the data set - this is why I needed this design.

On each new data point was appended to the NSMutableData and then the NSData attribute was set to the NSMutableData.

I suspect that because the NSData pointer wasn't changing (though its content was), that Core Data did not appreciate the amount of change. Calling -hasChanged on the NSManagedObjectContext showed that there had been changes, and calling -updatedObjects even listed the Data object as having changed. But the actual data that was being written seems to have been truncated (sometimes).

To work around this I changed things slightly. New data points are still appended to NSMutableData *but* NSData attribute is only set when sampling is completed. This means that there is a chance that a crash might result in truncated data - but for the most part this work around seems to have solved the problem.

Caveat emptor: the bug was always intermittent, so it is possible that is still there - but just harder to manifest.