# Cocoa app layout with Core Data and lots of business logic

Tags: iphone, arrays, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, core-data

For those who have seen my other questions: I am making progress but I haven't yet wrapped my head around this aspect.  I've been pouring over stackoverflow answers and sites like Cocoa With Love but I haven't found an app layout that fits (why such a lack of scientific or business app examples? recipe and book examples are too simplistic).

I have a data analysis app that is laid out like this:

[image: app layout]

Communication Manager (singleton, manages the hardware)
DataController (tells Comm.mgr what to do, and checks raw data it receives)
Model (receives data from datacontroller, cleans, analyzes and stores it)
MainViewController (skeleton right now, listens to comm.mgr to present views and alerts)

Now, never will my data be directly shown on a view (like a simple table of entities and attributes), I'll probably use core plot to plot the analyzed results (once I figure that out).  The raw data saved will be huge (10,000's of points), and I am using a c++ vector wrapped in an ObjC++ class to access it.  The vector class also has the encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder functions which use NSData as a transport for the vector.  I'm trying to follow proper design practices, but I'm lost on how to get persistent storage into my app (which will be needed to store and review old data sets).

I've read several sources that say the "business logic" should go into the model class.  This is how I have it right now, I send it the raw data, and it parses, cleans and analyzes the results and then saves those into ivar arrays (of the vector class).  However, I haven't seen a Core Data example yet that has a Managed Object that is anything but a simple storage of very basic attributes (strings, dates) and they never have any business logic.  So I wonder, how can I meld these two aspects?  Should all of my analysis go into the data controller and have it manage the object context?  If so, where is my model? (seems to break the MVC architecture if my data is stored in my controller - read: since these are vector arrays, I can't be constantly encoding and decoding them into NSData streams, they need a place to exist before I save them to disk with Core Data, and they need a place to exist after I retrieve them from storage and decode them for review).

Any suggestions would be helpful (even on the layout I've already started). I just drew some of the communication between objects to give you an idea.  Also, I don't have any of the connections between the model and view/view controllers yet (using NSLog for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While vector<> is great for handling your data that you are sampling (because of its support for dynamically resizing underlying storage), you may find that straight C arrays are sufficient (even better) for data that is already stored. This does add a level of complexity but it avoids a copy for data arrays that are already of a known and static size.

NSData's -bytes returns a pointer to the raw data within an NSData object. Core Data supports NSData as one its attribute types. If you know the size of each item in data, then you can use -length to calculate the number of elements, etc.

On the sampling side, I would suggest using vector<> as you collect data and, intermittently, copy data to an NSData attribute and save. Note: I ran into a bit of problem with this approach ([Truncated Core Data NSData objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144017/truncated-core-data-nsdata-objects)) that I attribute to Core Data not recognizing changes made to NSData attribute when it is backed by an NSMutableData object and that mutable object's data is changed.

As for MVC question. I would suggest that data (model) is managed in by Model. Views and Controllers can ask Model for data (or subsets of data) in order to display. But ownership of data is with the Model. In my case, which may be similar to yours, there were times when the Model returns abridged data sets (using Douglas-Peucker algorithm). The views and controllers were none the wiser that points were being dropped - even though their requests to the Model may have played in a role in that (graph scaling factors, etc.).

**Update**

Here is a snippet of code from my Data class which extends NSManagedObject. For a filesystem solution, NSFileHandle's -writeData: and methods for monitoring file offset might allow similar (better) management controls.

```
// Exposed interface for adding data point to stored data
- (void) addDatum:(double_t)datum
    {
    [self addToCache:datum];
    }

- (void) addToCache:(double_t)datum
    {
    if (cache == nil)
        {
        //  This is temporary. Ideally, cache is separate from main store, but
        //  is appended to main store periodically - and then cleared for reuse. 
        cache = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[self dataSet]];
        [cache retain];
        }
    [cache appendBytes:&datum length:sizeof(double_t)];
    //  Periodic copying of cache to dataSet could happen here...
    }

// Called at end of sampling.
- (void) wrapup
    {
    [self setDataSet:[NSData dataWithData:cache]];  // force a copy to alert Core Data of change
    [cache release];
    cache = nil;
    }
```

Comment: I have to use a mutable array because the data is continuously coming in (and I may have to preen values occasionally).  I would like the ability to save to disk from time to time, instead of waiting for the user to close the app (and then calling nsarchiver to write the file).  However, I'm not quite sure how I would go about dumping it incrementally, short of just rewriting the file each time I write it to disk.  As far as the model (since I can't find an authoritative answer on analysis app design), I've decided that my model is going to implement all of the methods to process its own data.

Comment: If you are simply writing data to disk, then I don't think that you'd need NSArchiver. I would think that during sampling, you could write bytes, track file offset (end), and write (append) more bytes periodically. When it comes time to read data back in, then you could either read it all into an NSData object - or, if data is too big, then manage your own "paging".

Comment: The objc++ class wrapper of vector that I wrote includes the method encodeWithCoder which copies the vector's block into an NSData object to be encoded, and initWithCoder to bring it back out. These both work. Using vector looked easier to me than writing an objc class to make NSMutableData act like an array (maybe this is possible). All I need are arrays that are mutable of type short, float, and double that have good performance for floating-point-heavy algorithms. I was also concerned whether or not it is a good design practice to put all of my analysis code into the NSManagedObject model.

Comment: I usually hide implementation details as far "down" as possible. The less that the rest of the application knows about complicated algorithms that could change, the better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be reading into Core Data a bit too much. I'm not that experienced with it, so I speak as a non-expert, but there are basically two categories of data storage systems.

First is the basic database, like SQLite, PostgreSQL, or any number of solutions. These are meant to store data and retrieve it; there's no logic so you have to figure out how to manage the tables, etc. It's a bit tricky at times but they're very efficient. They're best at managing lots of data in raw form; if you want objects with that data you have to create and manage them yourself.

Then you have something like Core Data, which shouldn't be considered a database as much as an "object persistence" framework. With Core Data, you create objects, store them, and then retrieve them as objects. It's great for applications where you have large numbers of objects that each contain several pieces of data and relationships with other objects.

From my limited knowledge of your situation, I would venture a guess that a true database may be better suited to your needs, but you'll have to make the decision there (like I said, I don't know much about your situation).

As for MVC, my view is that the view should only contain display code, the model should only contain code for managing the data itself and its storage, and the controller should contain the logic that processes the data. In your case it sounds like you're gathering raw data and processing it before storing it, in which case you'd want to have another object to process the data before storing it in the model, then a separate controller to sort, manage, and otherwise prepare the data before the view receives it. Again, this may not be the best explanation (or the best methods for your situation) so take it with a grain of salt.

EDIT: Also, if you're looking on getting into Core Data more, I like [this book](http://pragprog.com/titles/mzcd/core-data). It explains the whole object-persistence-vs-database concept a lot better than I can.